# pip WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I faced error which is pip can't download packages

the error is

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/f5/11/fc3de994aa4648632f3512ca18686fb82e6f250d82dda544a09f96726dae/pipenv-2023.11.15-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f23739c9d60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))
```

My ubuntu version **18.04.1** and **20.04.4**

**python version 3.8 / 3.12**

**pip version 23.3.1**

after I changed python version using

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8
```

below error happen when I use pip install

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pip
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7b37313f40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')':
```

before I changed python(python3.6) pip worked well

I saw many people have this problem and solved but even I tried every things in internet I counldn't solve this

**What I tried**

1. I tried internet connection

```
ping google.com
ping pypi.org
etc ....

---

result is 


PING pypi.org (151.101.64.223) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.64.223 (151.101.64.223): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=6.10 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.64.223 (151.101.64.223): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=6.12 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.64.223 (151.101.64.223): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=6.09 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.64.223 (151.101.64.223): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=6.14 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.64.223 (151.101.64.223): icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=6.11 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.64.223 (151.101.64.223): icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time=6.09 ms
^C
--- pypi.org ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5008ms
```

2. I reinstalled pip and python
   and apt-get update, changing to python2, remove alternatives about python
3. remove Anaconda python
4. use ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.8
5. install another version of python 7,8,9,10,11 etc
6. check curl working (i.e curl https://pypi.org/simple/flask-bcrypt/)
7. pip install --upgrade pip  --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

Comment: This seems like a network issue 'Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'

Comment: what did your ping requests say?

Comment: @journpy ping test works well. I can't understand why this happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem.

the reason was DNS problem....

I used 8.8.8.8 google. but it had problem so I changed DNS server and now works well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a network issue. Try the following to see what fixes it:

- Restart your network and ensure you have good connection.
- Try connecting to other networks
- Try using a VPN

Do note that `Network is unreachable'` error message could either mean there is a break in the connectivity chain somewhere along the way, or perhaps, a firewall somewhere is blocking you.

Comment: @journpyThanks for answering,
first thing I check google, pypi.org etc... and it works

second, I check `ping files.pythonhosted.org`. but it can't connect I think this is problem but I have mulitple server so I tried the other server working well in this server it worked.... even the both server is the same network... and both of them ufw status is inactive.

third, the server is The server I'm talking about is the company's thing ... so I can't use vpn for security....

Comment: Look at this part of my answer "... or perhaps, a firewall somewhere is blocking you." Please speak to your company's IT team for help. A VPN or any other way to bypass this would help